I have react-image-crop problems with IOS
It works perfectly in Android and desktop browsers, but I have issues with Iphone and Safari Mac
I am uploading an image cropping with react-image-crop and uploading to S3 AWS
Do you guys know any solution?
I am thinking about using another library, I would appreciate any suggestion
I tried changing some code in the back-end too. but the image does not even render in iphones the my AWS code gives the error 413 for macs
